# How to find the next blank column in VBA and populate it using VBA form

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set up a VBA form that will find the next empty column in a table and populate the empty cells using values entered into a form.

The current code basically finds the next empty cell in column B and resets the form after submitting it.

I will post images of the table and form I am using below.
[image]

[image]

Code:

```
Private Sub addButton1_Click()

    If surfactantCountBox.Value = "" Or wetterCountBox.Value = "" Or causticCountBox.Value = "" Then
        If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
        UserForm1.surfactantCountBox.SetFocus
        Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Call findEmpty
    Call resetForm

End Sub

Sub resetForm()

    surfactantCountBox.Value = ""
    wetterCountBox.Value = ""
    causticCountBox.Value = ""
    UserForm1.surfactantCountBox.SetFocus

End Sub

Sub findEmpty()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    For Each cell In ws.Columns(2).Cells
        If IsEmpty(cell) = True Then cell.Select: Exit For
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: It wouldn't let me add an actual picture so it added it as a link, but I went ahead and included the code as text as well.

Answer (score 0):

`ws.Columns(2)` refers to column B - your code is looking at each cell in column B, so will return the last row if anything.

Having said that, you don't have to look at each row/column.  Manually you can find the last column by going to the last cell - e.g. cell `XFD2` and pressing `Ctrl + Left` which will take you to the last column in row 2.

To do this in code:

```
Sub findEmpty()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    
    Dim NextEmptyCell As Range
    With ws
        'This is the same as going to XFD2 and pressing Ctrl+Left and then going one cell right.
        Set NextEmptyCell = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(, 1)
    End With
    
    Debug.Print NextEmptyCell.Address

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to find the next empty column in row 2.

```vb
Set rngEmpty = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)
```

We could incorporate that into the rest of the  code to add the data from the userform.

```vb
Private Sub addButton1_Click()
Dim rngEmpty As Range

    If surfactantCountBox.Value = "" Or wetterCountBox.Value = "" Or causticCountBox.Value = "" Then
        If MsgBox("Form is not complete. Do you want to continue?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo) <> vbYes Then
            Me.surfactantCountBox.SetFocus
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
    
    Set rngEmpty = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToRight).Offset(, 1)
    
    With rngEmpty
        .Value = Me.surfactantCountBox.Value
        .Offset(1).Value = Me.causticCountBox.Value
        .Offset(2).Value = Me.wetterCountBox.Value
    End With
    
    Call resetForm

End Sub
```